# How to add png files

Tags: colors, png, addition

Given are n layers represented by png files. These layers are overlapping each other. How do you add them correctly regarding transparency, alpha channel, and color?

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean by 'add them' together? Are you trying to merge (flatten) them into a single layer, and calculate what the resulting colour would be? And what programme are you trying to do this in?

Comment: "Transparency' and "alpha" are the same thing. The specifications detail what happens with transparency-on-color and transparency-on-transparency.

Comment: Yes, I try to merge them.